# Prove that there is a surjection $ f:X \to Y$ if and only if $ |Y| \le |X| $.

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

**Here's the problem:**

Let $X$ and $Y$ be sets.

Prove that there is a surjection

$$ f:X \to Y$$

if and only if

$$ |Y| \le |X| $$.

**My work so far:**

I am working on the following direction:

If $ |Y| \le |X| $ then there is a surjection $ f:X \to Y$.

I was given the following "hint" in class (though it hasn't done me much good):

Consider the function $h:Y \to X $

with map $y \mapsto h(x)$.

Take $f(h(y))=y$.

What if $x \ne h(y)?$

So, the idea makes intuitive sense to me, that if the cardinality of the domain is greater than or equal to the cardinality of the codomain, then there is a surjection because, well, there'd have to be more elements in the codomain for the elements in the domain to map to in order for it *not* to be surjective, but that's hardly a proof. Anyway, any guidance here would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: The statement is wrong, unless you assume $Y\ne\emptyset$.

Comment: How so? Take $X=\{0\}$ and $Y=\{0\}$ and let $f(0)=0$. The cardinalities of $X$ and $Y$ are equal and $f$ is surjective, no?

Comment: What @egreg is trying to say is that there is an injection from $\varnothing$ into $\{0\}$, but there is no surjection from $\{0\}$ onto $\varnothing$.

Comment: $Y=\{0\}$ is not empty. Consider $Y=\emptyset$ and $X=\{0\}$; we have $|Y|\le|X|$, but there is no surjection $X\to Y$.

Comment: Right, I'd misread the comment. Sorry about that. But, regardless, I've read the problem quite carefully, and it's not a mistake on my part as far as copying it here. So, I don't know what to make of this problem. I suppose I am to assume, in fact, that $Y$ is not empty?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The statement is wrong, unless we assume $Y\ne\emptyset$. So I'll go on under this additional assumption.

If $|Y|\le|X|$, there is an injection $f\colon Y\to X$. Let $y_0\in Y$. Define, for $x\in X$,
$$
g(x)=\begin{cases}
y & \text{if $f(y)=x$, for some $y\in Y$}\\
y_0 & \text{if $x\ne f(y)$, for all $y\in Y$}
\end{cases}
$$
Note that the $y$ in the first case is uniquely determined, because $f$ is injective.

Now it's clear that $g\colon X\to Y$ is surjective. And it's also clear why $Y$ must be nonempty.

For the converse, use the fact that a surjection has (under the axiom of choice) a right inverse.